# Events not working after route switching in Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events, backbone-routing

I have a Marionette based application, and now trying to include [Material Design Lite](https://getmdl.io/) via npm. Also, I have included the CSS for Material Design into my bundler and `gulp` flow and this is working fine. However, when I switch routes for example, I have a button with ripple effect on mysite/#A and then I go to mysite/#B and then come back to mysite/#A, the CSS is all fine but the Material Design's JS fails to function (no ripple effect etc.). I am using ES6 with Babel and am importing material design in `main.js` which starts the application. I also tried to re-import the same in the specific view, still no luck. 
The effects work if I refresh the page in the browser.
How can I make this work on changing URLs within the SPA ?
Please let me know if any other information is required regarding the project or router implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Finally! So, the problem was that MDL requires `componentHandler`'s `upgrade` to be called after dynamically elements are added to the DOM. With Marionette, I called that in view's `onDomRefresh` and works like a charm.